# Why doesn't passing toUpperCase to map work

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a question yesterday in which the poster was asking how to convert the case of an array's contents. I know that I can pass a reference to a function to map like:

```
function appendText (el){
    return el += ' - appended text';
}

['a','b'].map(appendText);  //["a - appended text", "b - appended text"]
```

But when I tried with

```
array.map(String.toUpperCase);
array.map(String.prototype.toUpperCase);
```

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toUpperCase called on null or undefined

Which makes it sound like the method isn't getting passed the element `map` would, as I understand it, be passing. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `appendText` expect an argument, `toUpperCase` doesn't as the string would be `this` so it does get the element from map but is not designed to use it. It's used as `'stuff'.toUpperCase()` not as `String.toUpperCase('stuff')`

Comment: Try `array.map(s => s.toUpperCase())`

Comment: @hsfzxjy That will upper case an array of values, but that's not the question.

Comment: I explained why it doesn't work which answer your question. Which tbh I'm pretty sure has been asked in SO before.

Comment: @GillesC Oh, of course.

Comment: @GillesC I think you're confused about who I addressed that to. Yes, you answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @1252748 GillesC points out the problem, and I just give a solution.

Comment: See @GillesC comment. You could use `bind()` to set the `this` value explicitly and then it will work: `array.map(String.prototype.toUpperCase.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase));`

Comment: A shorter version of @Jaco's code would be `array.map(Function.call.bind("".toUpperCase))`, or make a reusable binding function, like this: `var binder = Function.bind.bind(Function.call)` and use it like this: `array.map(binder("".toUpperCase))` Arrow functions make this all much nicer.

Comment: @squint `Function.bind.bind(Function.call)`. That looks interesting. Can you explain what's happening there?

Comment: @1252748: Yes, it's creating a version of the `.bind()` method that has the `.call()` method bound to its `this` value. So when you invoke that resulting function with a function as its first arg, you're invoking `.bind()` with `.call()` as its `this`, and the arg as its first argument. Because it's an invocation of `.bind()`, it returns a new function that is the `.call()` method with the function arg bound as call's `this` value. So `binder("".toUpperCase)` returns `.call()` with `toUpperCase` bound as `this`. When invoking that function, because the `this` value is already bound...

Comment: ...any further args supplied will simply be passed in the argument positions. And because the `.call()` method *invokes* its `this` value, it will ultimately invoke `toUpperCase` with the given arguments. Confusing, but effective.

Comment: ...I left out the important point that because the first argument to `.call` sets the `this` value of the function it's calling, the first argument given will be the `this` value of `toUpperCase`. So `var uc = binder("".toUpperCase)` and then `uc("foo")` is basically `"".toUpperCase.call("foo")`, which is `"foo".toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing anything to the `prototype` / extension method. Simply use an arrow function to pass in the value of the array item.

To answer the logic behind the question, you simply can't pass the context-less (e.g. no `this`) prototype method (that is, from the base `String` class). `map` will run the function by name with the value as the first parameter (as shown with `appendText(a)`)

```js
function appendText (el){
    return el += ' - appended text'
}

var array = ['a','b']

console.log(array.map(appendText))
console.log(array.map(a => appendText(a)))
console.log(array.map(a => a.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: Please comment if you are going to downvote, as I feel this answers the question in terms of correct output and the reason why you can't pass in a `prototype` method.

Comment: `Please comment if you are going to downvote, as I feel this answers your question` implies that it was me who downvoted you, which I did not.

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't, I just based this on your comment above to @hsfzxjy. Edited my comment to be clearer...